# Video player breaks JS code in IPad with webkitendfullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

I have a web application that works fine on web browser like Chrome on a PC. But I am facing a strange issue on when i try to open the same app on an IPad.
In my web application i show a video on one of my page. I use the below code for setting the video on my page on the Page load of my aspx page.

```
                 $get('dvVideo').innerHTML = '<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="600" height="337.5" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xyz?autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&color=white&theme=light" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

I have a javascript piece of code that returns the Parent of the Page.

```
        function GetHomeWindow()
        {
           var parent = window.parent;
           if (parent.name == 'Home')
           {
             return parent; 
           } 
        }
```

The above code works fine on a PC with Chrome, where i always get the parent page from which the Child Page had opened.
But in IPad the window.parent returns - **webkitendfullscreen** instead of the Parent page name.

This breaks the whole code of mine which is expecting a proper Page to be returned from the Javascript method.

Any Help would be really appreciated.